# Spring integration RecipientListRouter doesn't create multiple payloads

Tags: spring, spring-integration, integration

Please can any one help me with this issue, I configured my ReceipientListRouter as the documentation suggested:

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow routerFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(CHANNEL_INPUT)
                .routeToRecipients(r -> r
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .ignoreSendFailures(true)
                        .recipient(CHANNEL_OUTPUT_1)
                        .recipient(CHANNEL_OUTPUT_2)
                        .sendTimeout(1_234L))
                .get();
    } 

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = CHANNEL_OUTPUT_1, outputChannel = CHANNEL_END)
    public Object foo(Message<?> message) {
       message.gePayload();
      //  processing1() ...
    }

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = CHANNEL_OUTPUT_2, outputChannel = CHANNEL_END)
    public Object bar(Message<?> message) {
       message.gePayload();
      //  processing2() ...
    }
```

I expect to get this workflow:

```
CHANNEL_INPUT(payload-1) |----> CHANNEL_OUTPUT_1(payload-2) 
                         |----> CHANNEL_OUTPUT_2(payload-3)
```

where payload-2 on the input of the *foo activator* equals the payload-1 and payload-3 on the input of the *bar activator* equals payload-1

But the actual workflow is:

the payload-2 on the input of the *foo activator* equals payload-1 but the payload-3 on the input of the *bar activator* equals payload-2 message of the output of *foo activator*

```
it seems like this is the actual workflow
CHANNEL_INPUT(payload-1)----> CHANNEL_OUTPUT_1(payload-2)----> CHANNEL_OUTPUT_2(payload-3)
```

after debugging I notice that *message.getHeader()* are not the same (it actually contain the "sequenceNumber" and the "sequenceSize") but for the *message.getPayload*  are as described above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the message is immutable, the payload is not (unless it's an immutable object such as a String).

If you mutate the payload in service1, the mutation will be seen in service2.

You need to clone/copy the payload before mutating it if you don't want service2 to see the mutation.

Comment: It's not a framework responsibility to make a decision for you to clone or copy a payload: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2513, https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2979